# Update a mysql table based on another. Complicated query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Short about my tables:** I have 2 tables: `content`, `users`

`content` structure is something like:
id | title   | cpc | user | active

```
users is:
```

id | user | monetos

**Idea** - I want to select `contet.*` rows which have `content.active` = 1 **(n)**. Having this data, `SELECT` `users.monetos` WHERE `users.id`=`content.user` from previous query.
And now, by maximum **(n)** steps i decrement `users.monetos` value by **content.cpc** value 
and **on the moment when **users.monetos***=0 or less than 0, i want to update `content` and SET active='0'*

By words, i want like to share **users.monetos** amount to each **content** entry (**content.cpc** for each). And there's no more **users.monetos** make the current `content` 
entry inactive. And do this vor every **content.user**
What i'he done at this moment is shown below. I now it looks really bad, but i already don't know what to do. Count on you guys. Thank you.

```
$kak2 = array();
$rs16 = $connector->query("SELECT user FROM content WHERE active='1'");


while($rw16 = $connector->fetchArray($rs16))
{
 $users_ids[] = $rw16['user'];    
}

$user_info2 = $connector->fetchArray("SELECT monetos,id FROM users WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$users_ids).")");

while($user_info = $connector->fetchArray($user_info2))
{
    $current_entry_info2 = $connector->query("SELECT cpc,id FROM content WHERE user='$user_info[id]' ORDER BY date DESC");

    while ($current_entry_info = $connector->fetchArray($current_entry_info2))
    {
        $user_info['monetos']= $user_info['monetos'] - $current_entry_info['cpc'];
        if($user_info['monetos'] = 0)
        {
            $updt = $connector->query("UPDATE content SET active='0' WHERE id='$current_entry_info[id]' LIMIT 1");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do your variable names have any logical meaning? It always helps to understand code when the variables are named in a way that describes what they refer to.

Comment: Just edited it . Check it out please

Answer (score 0):

I think i have got the idea of what you are trying to do so have contructed a small code snippit which i think should do what you are after.

note this is untested code

```
/** get the cost of all content for all users **/
$query = "select b.id, sum(a.cpc) as cpc from content a
join users b on a.user= b.id
group by b.id where a.active = 1"

/** cycle each user **/
foreach($rows = $connector->fetchArray($query) as $row ) {
    $menotos = $row['cpc'];
    $query = "select id, cpc from content where user={$row['id']}"
    /** cycle each users content **/
    foreach($contents = $connector->fetchArray($query) as $content) {
        $menotos -= $content['cpc'];
        if($menotos <= 0) {
            $disable[] = $content['id'];
        }
    }
    if( isset($disable) ) {
        $connector->query("update content set active=0 where id in(" . implode(',', $disable) . ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: it think you got it. just a small moment: $menotos = $row['cpc']; 
cpc, is cost for each content row, but $menotos is like an ammount of coins which every user have so $menotos = $row['menotos']. i'm gonna update and test it.
can't wait for test it. thank you very much.